# Is there an equivalent of skimages' piecewiseaffinetransform in opencv?

Tags: opencv

skimage has piecewiseaffineTransform , is there an equivalent for that in opencv ?

If not, can I slice the image and use affineTransform, warpAffine in opencv over indiidual sliced images to implement piecewiseAffineTransform ?

Answer (score 1):

In OpenCV there is no such function. This lib can help you [imgwarp-opencv](https://github.com/cxcxcxcx/imgwarp-opencv)

Or you can use [remap](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/remap/remap.html) function, if you have dense mapping. To get it you can [calculate perspective transform](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getperspectivetransform) for each quadrangle and calculate dense map.